# Computer vision - two frames, overlapping bounding boxes

Tags: yolo, object-recognition

Situation:

A bed is there in a room at some x, y position.  On the bed,  there's an apple at the center of the bed.

Now my code should give an output that there's an apple at the center of the bed,  or like an apple on the top left corner of the bed.

Can someone pls help me to know if how could I solve this problem using YOLO/OpenCV/Tensorflow/Torch, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer for Yolo. What are you looking for is nested or overlap detection right? It can be done using Yolo. 1 **important thing**, when you annotating your dataset, you have to **include the nested example** as well. If you only label bed and apple as separated object in your dataset, Yolo won't detect the nested object. You also have to include image where there is apple on top of the bed, and draw 2 bounding boxes for each object. See : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/2519

Example credits to **pkhigh** on github : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/2965

[image]